# How to query the CostController API for cost forecast using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to query the Cost Controller API of AWS for the cost forecast using `boto3`. Here is the code:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ce', region_name='us-east-1', aws_access_key_id=key_id, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
#the args object presents the filters
data = client.get_cost_forecast(**args)
```

The result is:

```
AttributeError: 'CostExplorer' object has no attribute 'get_cost_forecast'
```

But the actual documentation for the API says that it provides the `get_cost_forecast()` function.

Comment: Are you using the lastest version of boto3 and botocore?

Comment: In fact, botocore was throwing that error. And I figured out that the problem is in the version I am using, although I called the get_cost_and_usage() method and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method get_cost_forecast, you can refer below document to get cost forecast,

[Boto3 CostForecast](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_forecast)

eg.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ce')
response = client.get_cost_forecast(
TimePeriod={
    'Start': 'string',
    'End': 'string'
},
Metric='BLENDED_COST'|'UNBLENDED_COST'|'AMORTIZED_COST'|'NET_UNBLENDED_COST'|'NET_AMORTIZED_COST'|'USAGE_QUANTITY'|'NORMALIZED_USAGE_AMOUNT',
Granularity='DAILY'|'MONTHLY'|'HOURLY',
},
PredictionIntervalLevel=123
```

)

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out that the version of botocore I am using 1.8.45 does not support the method get_cost_forecast(). An upgrade to the version 1.9.71 is needed. I hope that this will help other people facing this issue.